# Extracting an array of integers using a regular expression in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm having real difficulty with this but I'm no javascript expert. All I want to do is get myself an array of all matches in a string which match a given regExp. The regExp being this :

```
[0-9]+
```

ie. Any integer.

So If I pass the string "12  09:8:76:::54  12" I should get

arr[0]="12"
arr[1]="09"
arr[2]="8"
arr[3]="76"
arr[4]="54"
arr[5]="12"

Easy? Not for me! I could do this in vb.net no problem with regexp.matches(string) (something like that anyway). I thought that the javascript method .exec would also give me an array however it only returns the first match. What's going on? Code...

```
function testIt(){
    splitOutSelection2("123:::45  0::12312 12:17"); 
}


function splitOutSelection2(sSelection){
    var regExp = new RegExp("[0-9]+","g");
    var arr = regExp.exec(sSelection);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the answers work but I was wanting to keep my regExp object rather than specify it at the time of use. So simply changing the function to...

```
function splitOutSelection2(sSelection){
    var regExp = new RegExp("[0-9]+","g");
    var arr = sSelection.match(regExp);
};
```

..is what I was looking for. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction though to all who have replied.

Answer (score 3):

```
arr = sSelection.match(/[0-9]+/g);
```

should do.

`g` is the global modifier that you need to get all the matches, not just the first one.

Comment: Thanks, this works. I realise that I should be using match and not exec. I was specifying the global modifier in my regExp declaration. But it is 'match' that is the key. My code can be rewritten as..

    function splitOutSelection2(sSelection){
        var regExp = new RegExp("[0-9]+","g");
        var arr = sSelection.match(regExp);
    };

Answer (score 1):

something like:

```
var arrMatch = "12 09:8:76:::54 12".match(/[0-9]+/g);
alert(arrMatch);
```

.match will return an array if global is set (and matches are found of course).
[0-9]+ means it will search for not only single digits, but also match 12, 09, 76.

Comment: Thanks. I initially thought that match wasn't working but it was not working because I hadn't set the g flag. This is why I went down the exec route which was incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

According to the doc, exec return the first match. You should use match instead.

```
var arr = sSelection.match(/[0-9]+/g);
```

or

```
var arr = sSelection.match(/\d+/g);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function splitOutSelection2(sSelection){
    return sSelection.split(/[^0-9]+/g);
};
```

Negate the regExp and use String#split.

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure this will work too. Is using split and a negated match more efficient than using exec?